How to copy the modified files which are retrieved as part of git diff in azure pipeline
We were able to get the list of the modified files with the help of git diff command.
After getting the list I would like to copy the modified files to the development server. Can anyone help me how can we copy over the modified files to the server with the same folder structure.

Ideally you should make a reproducible build and copy everything over

Thanks for the suggestion @Daniel, We have files around~20k, so looking out for any other alternate workaround.

It really depends on what platform/os etc. not enough details here

Sorry for not providing the details, we are trying to copy over the files to windows server 2022

You can try to use the PowerShell task to execute the following script to copy the modified files from a directory (source directory) on the agent machine to another one (destination directory). The destination directory can be one either in local filesystem of the agent machine or in a file share that can be accessible from the agent machine.
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Show Infor'
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      Write-Host "Getting the list of modified files from all commits associated with current pipeline run..."
      $prefix_url = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
      $project = "$(System.TeamProject)"
      $buildId = $(Build.BuildId)
      $url = "${prefix_url}${project}/_apis/build/builds/${buildId}/changes?includeSourceChange=true&api-version=7.0"
      $headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
      $response=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers
      $changesCount = $response.count

      $modifiedFiles= git diff HEAD HEAD~$changesCount --name-only

      Write-Host "Start copying the modified files..."
      $srcDir = "{Source directory that contains all the modified files}"
      $destDir = "{Destination directory that the files are copied to}"

      foreach ($file in $modifiedFiles)
      {
          Write-Host "------------------------------"
          $srcFile = "$srcDir/$file"
          $destFile = "$destDir/$file"
          Write-Host "Copying file: $srcFile ---> $destFile"

          $parentDir = Split-Path -Parent $destFile
          if (-not (Test-Path $parentDir))
          {
              # If the directory does not exist, create it.
              New-Item -Path $parentDir -ItemType Directory
          }

          Copy-Item "$srcFile" -Destination "$destFile"
      }


